# cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<const ClassType,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'const ClassType &'

Tags: c++, vector, stl, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I am creating a C++ text game for a computer science class project. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015. The game is about using items in battles to defeat enemies. The items return results. In this project I was using std::shared_ptrs to hold results in std::shared_ptrs that hold items in std::vectors that other classes use. But when I compiled an earlier version of the program that printed all the items within a vector of items within the OffensiveEntity class in a loop, it didn't display anything, so I replaced all of the std::shared_ptrs with unique ones. When I compile the program now, I get three

```
Error C2664 'Result::Result(Result &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 
'std::unique_ptr<const Result,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'const Result &'
```

errors about Result and another about Item. It seems to be about the constructor, but when I click on the link, it just takes me to some random part of < memory >. Could it be because of how I use them in a loop? Like:

```
for (const std::unique_ptr<Item> & i : m_offensiveEntity->GetItems())
{
     //Do something with each pointer
}
```

Or

```
if (i->Use() == std::make_unique<const Result>(Result(0, 0, 0)))
{
     //more code
}
```

Is it because of how the Result objects are const?
Heres the link to the full code within a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Z6s23Jac), if its necessary.

Comment: Show the actual line where the error message occurs.

Comment: Note if you have an error in template code in `<memory>`, your compiler will then say something like "instantiated from" and give you some more relevant lines, eventually coming to somewhere in the code you wrote.

Comment: You changed the fundamental smart-pointer type because of a lack of display output? Dare I ask, how was *that* course of action chosen as an attempt to remediate that problem? If more than one smart pointer is to host referral to some dynamic object, `std::shared_ptr` is the obvious solution. if not, then `std::unique_ptr` is probably the ticket.  This is potentially as pristine an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) one could contrive.

Comment: I guess your right a little bit. I thought it wasn't displaying anything because memory was incorrectly being referenced through pointers. So I guess I thought unique pointer would fix that problem because you can't copy the address on to another pointer right?

Comment: In `Item::Use` you try to construct a `std::unique_ptr<const Result>` with `std::make_unique` from another `std::unique_ptr<const Result>` (from `m_mainResult` to be precise). But the `Result` struct doesn't have a constructor that takes a reference to a `std::unique_ptr<const Result>`, so that construction fails. You need to dereference the `m_mainResult` pointer to call the copy-constructor of `Result` there.

Comment: I looked at the output code and searched it through Visual Studio but it couldn't find where it was

Comment: Were you replying to me? If so, next time add @Corristo so I get notified. 
The call to make_unique is in line 220 on pastebin.

Comment: @Corristo: Like this?: return std::make_unique<const Result>(&m_mainResult);

Comment: No, & returns a pointer to the unique_ptr, you need to dereference the unique_ptr. It should be `std::make_unique<const Result>(*m_mainResult);`

Comment: @Corristo I am asking this because it didn't work

Comment: @Corristo Do I now define a copy constructor in Result? Or can it use the default one? And do I do this to this line too:     return std::make_unique<const Result>(*Result(0, 0, 0));

Comment: @Chopdops The copy-constructor is implicitly defined by the compiler for you, at least as long as all members are copyable (which is true for `Result`, but not for `Item`, as it has a `unique_ptr` as a member). But you have several places in your code where you're trying to create a new `unique_ptr` from an existing one. All of these need to be fixed.

Comment: Regarding `std::make_unique<const Result>(Result(0,0,0));`: This works, but will cause an unnecessary move. You can simply call `std::make_unique<const Result>(0, 0, 0);`.

Comment: In general you're trying to copy `unique_ptr`s all over the place. This is not gonna work. You should consider rethinking the entire architecture here. It seems to me most of these `unique_ptr`s are totally unnecessary and the inheritance-based polymorphism seems forced. (e.g. `Item` inherits publicly from `GameEnttity`, so now it provides both `getDurability` and `getHP` to access the same data)

Comment: So in order for some things to work correctly I also have to define a Item copy constructor?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't prepare all that good. I only have one day left so I Ill have to work with a crappy archetecture. But thanks for helping me! I got rid of two of the errors already.

Comment: If you want to copy `Item`s, then yes. But from a semantic point of view copying items means duplicating them, so that doesn't make much sense. Most likely moving them will suffice.

Comment: But the most problematic part really is copying the `unique_ptr`s into vectors in your code. Take `OffensiveEntity::GetItems`: Here you try to append copies of existing `unique_ptr` to a new vector of `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @Corristo So literally when the cmd didn't display anything it had nothing to do with the pointers? At this point should I just start over?

Comment: I can't tell, it might have been a problem with pointers pointing to wrong items/results, or it might not have. If you want unique ownership, then `unique_ptr` is the correct thing to do, and the compiler errors will help you figure out where you accidentally made a copy of a `shared_ptr` where it should have been a clone of the real object before.

Comment: But the first thing I'd do is get rid of unnecessary pointers in the first place. `Result` is a perfectly fine value type, you don't need to use `std::unique_ptr<const Result>` but could use a plain `Result` (or `const Result` if it really doesn't change) instead.

Comment: Well, I got it working. Just coding the rest of the framework. And yeah, making result be held in a pointer was pretty stupid, I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks for all your help!